# Core Data - Fetch object with optional attribute

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I have an `EntityA` which has an optional attribute int32 `result`. When I create `EntityA` I do not  set the `result` attribute. Then later on when I fetch it I expect it to have `nil` value but for some reason it's set to `3` even though I have not set this attribute.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*1st possible issue:*
You have set a default value in the model editor. Select the attribute and check the inspector.

*2nd possible issue:*
You are retrieving or showing the wrong value. Show the code you are using to find out that result is '3'.

*3rd possible issue:*
You are setting the value later inadvertently, perhaps in a loop or something similar. Do a text search for the attribute to find a possible occurrence in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Your int32 will be stored wrapped into a NSNumber object. If you don't provide a value, no NSNumber object will be created - sql will treat it as NULL.

The iOS Core Data Programming Guide says:

> You can specify that an attribute is optional—that is, it is not
>   required to have a value. In general, however, you are discouraged
>   from doing so—especially for numeric values (typically you can get
>   better results using a mandatory attribute with a default value—in the
>   model—of 0). The reason for this is that SQL has special comparison
>   behavior for NULL that is unlike Objective-C's nil. NULL in a database
>   is not the same as 0, and searches for 0 will not match columns with
>   NULL.

So, it may be better to either make the attribute mandatory and set it to a distinct value, or to pass in NSNumber from the start.